# How to set condition to get most recent last modified record in process builder?

Tags: process-builder

Can someone help me with the process builder. I have a Junction object 'Account related contract' and child object 'Contract'. I have created a process builder on Junction object to update the field 'Active Contract Number' on Account if any Junction object is added through that account. It updates the contract number on Account. But I also want that if another Junction record is added to that Account then 'Active Contract Number' field on account should reflect the number of that contract who is recently updated. 
Please suggest how to give condition or how to get most recent modified record from contract in process builder.
Is there any way to get this record.

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

One way that I can think of is by calling apex method.So it will give you flexibility on how you want to query and manipulate your data.

The method must use @InvocableMethod annotation.For more info, you can refer to [InvocableMethod Annotation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm) and also here [How to class from Process Builder](http://salesforceworld4u.blogspot.com.au/2015/05/how-to-call-apex-class-from-process.html)